# How can i Implement caching in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have iframe where i am loading external document.That document has a big data to load,and i have angular application where i don't want every time this big data to be loaded again and again through that iframe,so i want to cache that.Is there a way to implement this with the frame out of the box?

I have tried until now with route Reuse Strategy provider but it does not work.

```
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The iframe isn't relevant. Caching is determined by the HTTP response headers sent by `https://example.com`.

Mnot has a [good overview of caching](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), but you'll probably want something like:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
```

… which says it is should be cached for a week.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the data that is coming is live.Is there some way to decetc if there are changes and just in that way to load the data from the iframe again?

Comment: Use an ETag instead: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#VALIDATE

Comment: I've tried this now <iframe Cache-Control: max-age="604800" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe> and it is not working.It loads the data again

Comment: @Trajce12 — I said "HTTP response headers" not "HTML attributes".

Comment: How can i set them ?

Comment: Depends on `https://example.com`'s HTTP server and/or server-side programming language.